# Javascript div slider no jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am looking to write a javascript div slider. I tried JQuery plugins for div sliding. However since our application is dynamically generated, somehow the current jQuery plugins don't seem to render the slider correctly.

Hence thought to see if I could write  a simple slider that will toggle two divs in a slider way.

Basically, I would have two div and one left button and one right bottom.

```
<img src='images/left'></img>
<div id='content-one'>My First content </div>
<div id='content-two'>My Second content </div>
<img src='images/right'></img>
```

So when I click the right button, the first content should slide to the second (horizontally). Same way, I could flip it back with the left button. Having an ability to have a 1 second delay between transition would be helpful.

Any pointer on how to write this will be really helpful.

Thx

Comment: why put 'no jquery' in your title and tag the question jquery?

Comment: good point...i thought someone who is good in jquery may also know an alternative in Javascript..actually, i am fine with using regular query effect if they are not jquery plugins..

Comment: I'm sure there is a jquery plugin that can do what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This what you were looking for? [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mNAsd/3/).

> Doesn't use jQuery.
> Note slight change to layout (content DIVs are in
> a container).
> The CSS for overflow, display, padding and margin is
> required.

I just wrote the most basic linear scroll, you can modify it as you want.

Comment: I overcomplicated my solution, you can scroll by just `.offsetWidth` when the container DIV has the same size as the content DIV

Comment: Brilliant coding friend...loved the way u wrote the PrettyScroll function. It just works like a charm...I was able to learn lot of css and JS options from ur code..I am now going over your code to understand what magic you did ! I had one question - I am trying it myself - thought u could give me some pointer. When I press right button, "content one" moved to left and "content two" is shown.. Now, if I press the right again, is it possible I can move the "Content-two" to left, and show "content one" ? Hope you can give me some tips. I want to see if I can write it myself !

Comment: I'd do this with `.cloneNode(true);`, clone the first content, append the clone to the end, scroll right as normal then set `.scrollLeft = 0` and (optional if static, to save processing) remove cloned node. Same again for scrolling left from first to last, append a clone of the first node, jump-scroll to it, then scroll left as normal & remove it. If you're not removing it, make sure you don't keep adding new ones.

Comment: Another way to do this is have the first and last content nodes as blank, and scroll for twice as long, jumping between them in the middle.